# Winsor returns function

Tags: r, psych

The below is an extract of a zoo object which I am trying to winsorize using `winsor` from `psych` package:

```
x <- structure(c(0.0400337546529555, -0.0320371743076633, 0.0106006766976862, 
-0.011406282992093, -0.018676165248018, 0.0275956214868875, 0.00473575019758404, 
0.0986083620222542, 0.00615420656427005, 0.00709069372334476), .Names = c("1984-01", 
"1984-02", "1984-03", "1984-04", "1984-05", "1984-06", "1984-07", 
"1984-08", "1984-09", "1984-10"), index = structure(c(5113, 5144, 
5173, 5204, 5234, 5265, 5295, 5326, 5357, 5387), class = "Date"), class = c("zooreg", 
"zoo"), frequency = 1)
```

I use:

```
winsor(x, trim=0.1)
```

I get the following:

```
function () 
.Last.value
<environment: namespace:gdata>
```

I tried the function with the following data which has the same class (i.e. `zoo` and `zooreg`):

```
a <- structure(c(1, 2, 3), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
        "a"), index = structure(c(5113, 5144, 5173), class = "Date"), frequency = 1, class = c("zooreg", 
    "zoo"))
```

It worked fine with `a` but not sure why it returns the above for that specific type of data `x`.

Comment: `x` in `winsor` must be vector, matrix or data.frame.  Does not support `zoo` object. Convert your data first.

Comment: @rbm  It worked fine with other data with the same class. I updated the question with that data.

Comment: oh, because you're missing dim. run `dim(x)=c(10,1)` and it'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` in `winsor` must be vector, matrix or data.frame. Does not support `zoo` objects. Convert/extract your data first, e.g.:

```
winsor(coredata(x), trim=0.1)
```

gives

```
> winsor(coredata(x), trim=0.1)
     1984-01      1984-02      1984-03      1984-04      1984-05      1984-06 
 0.040033755 -0.020012266  0.010600677 -0.011406283 -0.018676165  0.027595621 
     1984-07      1984-08      1984-09      1984-10 
 0.004735750  0.045891215  0.006154207  0.007090694
```

*Update*

the `x` in OP question is missing dimenstion, adding
    dim(x)=c(10,1)
makes it work:

```
> dim(x)=c(10,1)
> winsor(x)
                      X
1984-01-01  0.030083248
1984-02-01 -0.012860259
1984-03-01  0.010600677
1984-04-01 -0.011406283
1984-05-01 -0.012860259
1984-06-01  0.027595621
1984-07-01  0.004735750
1984-08-01  0.030083248
1984-09-01  0.006154207
1984-10-01  0.007090694
```